# What is wrong with my algorithm to render rectangle in 1D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, drawing

I am trying to make optimal algorithm to draw rectangle onto 1D array. I wrote this function:

```
/** Draws a rectangle in 1D array
 * Arguments:
 *   pixmap      - 1D array of Color
 *   color       - rectangle color
 *   w           - rectangle width
 *   h           - rectanhle height
 *   x           - x position, negative coordinates are outside draw area
 *   y           - y position, negative coordinates are outside draw area
 *   pixmapWidth - width of the image (height can be deducted from width if needed but is practically unnecessary) */
void rectangle(std::vector<int>& pixmap, const int& color, const int w, const int h, int x, const int y, const int pixmapWidth)
{
    if(x>=pixmapWidth)
        return;
    if(x+w<0)
        return;
    if(y+h<0)
        return;
    // Width of one consistent line of color of the rectangle
    // if the rectangle is partially out of pixmap area,
    // thw width is smaller than rectangle width
    const int renderWidth = std::min(w, pixmapWidth-x);
    // offset in the arrray where the rendering starts
    // 0 would be for [0,0] coordinate
    int tg_offset = y*pixmapWidth+x;
    // maximum offset to ever render, which is the array size
    const int tg_end = pixmap.size();
    int lines = 0;

    for(; tg_offset<tg_end && lines<h; tg_offset+=pixmapWidth) {
        for(int cx=0; cx<renderWidth; ++cx) {
            // This check keeps failing and my program crashes
            if(tg_offset+cx >= pixmap.size())
                throw "Oh no, what a bad thing to happen!";
            pixmap[tg_offset+cx] = color;
        }
        lines++;
    }
}
```

Note that I know there's a lot of picture drawing libraries, but I'm trying to learn by doing this. But now I'm stuck and I need help.

The problem is that in the inner loop, condition `if(tg_offset+cx >= pixmap.size())` keeps failing meaning I am trying to render outside the array. I have no idea why this keeps happening.

Example problematic code:

```
const int pixmap_width = 20;
const int pixmap_height = 20;
std::vector<int> pixmap(pixmap_width*pixmap_height);
// tries to render outside the array
rectangle(pixmap, 0, 10, 10, -1, 18, pixmap_width);
```

Here is a testcase including ASCII output of the pixmap: http://ideone.com/SoJPFF
I don't know how could I improve the question any more...

Comment: Well, what's `pixmap.size()`? Where and how is `pixmap` initialized?

Comment: To be honest "render rectangle to 1D array" sounds even worse then "fit a square peg in a round hole". Why are You even doing that?

Comment: do you have some parameters so that i can try to run it?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik pixmap is std::vector, which is a basic class for arrays. It's size is about 15k items, since it represents LCD screen.

Comment: @ldgorman Try anything with x = -1 and y near the bottom side of the screen area. You can replace `Color` with `int` or `bool`.

Comment: Show [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), complete with the code setting up and passing the arguments. I don't see anything wrong with the code you've shown; to the extent there is a problem, it likely likes in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: Well, you are not handling negative `x` or `y`, or large height. Just as you clip excessive width (c.f. `renderWidth`), you likely need to clip excessive height, and clamp negative `x` and `y` to zero.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I tried to clip it but I only ended up with rectangles randomly dissapearing. Here is a testcase: http://ideone.com/SoJPFF

Comment: Seems like you could quickly find the error if you single-stepped your code in the debugger.

Comment: `const int w, const int h` should they not be 20, 20 or are you trying to draw a rect inside a bigger space

Comment: @JimMischel I did that, I see what goes wrong but not how to fix it.

Comment: You need something like `if (x < 0) {w += x; x = 0}; if (y < 0) {h += y; y = 0;}` before calculating `renderWidth`. You also need to calculate `renderHeight` similarly to `renderWidth`, if you need to deal with the case where a rectangle sticks out the bottom of the pixmap.

Comment: @Amadeus negative coordinates are simply "*before*" the draw area - off the screen.

Comment: I think the for should be `for(; tg_offset<tg_end+x && lines<h; tg_offset+=pixmapWidth)`

Answer (score 0):

Making no changes produces a quadrilateral. Is this not the desired functionality?

```
    for(; tg_offset<tg_end && lines<h; tg_offset+=pixmapWidth) {
        cout <<"" << endl;
        for(int cx=0; cx<renderWidth; ++cx) {
            cout << " " << pixmap[tg_offset+cx]; 
            // This check keeps failing and my program crashes
            if(tg_offset+cx >= pixmap.size())
                throw "Oh no, what a bad thing to happen!";
            pixmap[tg_offset+cx] = color;
        }
        lines++;
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> pixmap(16);
    pixmap = { 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1 };
    int color = 0;
    int w = 4;
    int h = 4;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int pixmapWidth = 4;

   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
   rectangle(pixmap, color, w, h, x, y, pixmapWidth);

   return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
Hello World

 1 1 1 1
 1 0 0 1
 1 0 0 1
 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: try `x=-1`, `y=15`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the output you want when x or y are negative. In your actual algorithm things goes wrong if x is negative due the fact that `tg_offset` goes back, so the `tg_offset + cx` can fail.

To solve this you can limit the second `for` to avoid this, like this:

```
for(int cx=0; cx<std::min(renderWidth, tg_end - tg_offset); ++cx)
```

but I think that limiting x and y to be only positive is more correct:

```
if ( x < 0 ) x = 0;
if ( y < 0 ) y = 0;
```

Comment: Demos: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/682c9ba186a9947c and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc4315bc7bf38bab

Answer (score 0):

I think a large part of the problem with your function is it being a lot more complex than it needs to be. Here's a much simpler version of your function, done by simply looping over `x` and `y`.

```
void rectangle(std::vector<int>& pixmap, const int& color, const int width, const int height,
               int left, const int top, const int pixmapWidth)
{
    for (int x = std::max(left, 0); x < left + width && x < pixmapWidth; x++)
    for (int y = std::max(top, 0); y < top + height && y*pixmapWidth + x < pixmap.size(); y++)
        pixmap[y*pixmapWidth + x] = color;
}
```